# PHP - shoutbox accept a php tag or html tag as a text not a code

Tags: php

i'm developing a website that has a shoutbox application,

what i want to do is how to accept if the user or a guest is inserting php tags as his/her message or shout just like want you can see on the image..

i'm using mysql_real_escape_string for the guest name and for the message..

i want php to treat that as a text and display it as a text not a tag or a code..

when i entered a shout like that, no message appears just like the shout of the (guest:3:34pm) no message displayed, and when i check my database to see if the shout is inserted.. no data inserted on the messages column of my tb_shoutbox..

i tried it on facebook chat i enter a php tag and html tag and it accept that kind of message.. how to do that..

some help please..

[image: shoutbox]

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert certain characters (such as "<") to HTML entities. The [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function can be used like so:

> echo htmlentities($guest_comment, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');

Comment: should i rather use this than mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is used when you're inserting into the DB. htmlentities is used when you're outputting data. mysql_real_escape_string -> database -> htmlentities -> output

Answer (score 1):

To build on Wayne Whitty's completely correct answer and answer on your comment on his answer:

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is used when you want to insert a variable's data into a MySQL database using a MySQL query, without breaking the query with the variable's content.

That prevents people from doing [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) on your shoutbox.

[htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on the other hand is used when you want to stop people from breaking your PHP script (which can be very unpleasant). It encodes the string you gives it into pure html. It's like it is telling the browser that this string, whatever is in it, should be displayed right of to the user. No code parsing is done.

**So to answer your question:** Somewhere in your code you have a PHP line that echoes the messages from the database/file. You need to modify that line so it first encodes the message with htmlentities, then shows it to the use

Answer (score 0):

You should use [HTMLEntities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in order to display tags as plain text.